# After upgrade to .NET 8 and Microsoft.Identity.Web 2.x: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition'

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, .net-8.0, microsoft.identity.web

I've just upgraded

- .net 7 blazor server asp.net app to .NET 8
- Microsoft.Identity.Web nuget from 1.x to 2.x

and I'm getting exception from `app.Build()`:

> 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Sylex.ISYS.SharepointPortal.ISharePointClientContextFactory Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> Sylex.ISYS.SharepointPortal.SharePointClientContextFactory': Could not
> load type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.Identity.Web, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae'.)

Here is the code that worked before:

```
builder.services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                   
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("Basic", null) 
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))            
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(sharepointScopes)
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISharePointClientContextFactory, SharePointClientContextFactory>(); //this type uses ITokenAquisition
```

[image]

Comment: Please share you .csproj file. Ideally provide a [mre].

Comment: I can make it work in my side to get the access token so I'm afraid it's related to the migration. Or could you please share the content of the interface and the  implement?

Answer (score 1):

I had a test in my side and it worked for me to use `ITokenAcquisition` to generate access token. I'm using `Microsoft.Identity.Web with version 2.16.0`.

I'm afraid the issue is related to how we migrate from .net 7 to .net 8. I have a detailed steps about how I migrate [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730702/14574199) before testing `ITokenAcquisition`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After I upgraded all other unrelated packages, the problem disappeared.

No sure which one was causing the error:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" Version="16.1.24322.12000" />
<PackageReference Include="Blazor.ContextMenu" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Blazored.Typeahead" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="libphonenumber-csharp" Version="8.13.27" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />  
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.16.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Playwright" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="5.3.3" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="moment.net" Version="1.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars" Version="24.1.43" />
<PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns" Version="24.1.43" />
<PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes" Version="24.1.43" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Toolbelt.Blazor.HotKeys2" Version="3.2.1" />
```

Comment: it's amazing.....