# Microsoft Identity Platform not available as authentication type choice for a Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, blazor, entra

I am looking into adding Azure AD (Entra) to a Blazor application, as the title says, I can only select these authentication type options:

[image]

While in comparison, a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjnDFnOiMwk) shows this:

[image]

Further on it shows the kind of options I would need for my Entra integration.

**How can I add Microsoft Identity Platform as an option?**

Comment: Yes,Microsoft Identity Platform is not supported directly for .NET 8.0 template.If you want, you can configure it manually from [Connected Services](https://i.imgur.com/iwJGJrl.png).

Comment: @Harshitha not _yet_ then? I will look into that.

Comment: For Blazor Apps,`Microsoft Identity Platform` for .NET 8.0 version is currently available only for [Blazor WASM](https://i.imgur.com/xGk7xAH.png)

Comment: I tried WASM, even that seems experimental at best. I will look into adding it manually.

Comment: that's because there's a big change in .net 8 for blazor, that we say blazor web app to replace the origin blazor server. In VS we haven't had a template for blazor web app to integrate Azure AD, but that doesn't mean we can't integrate AAD into blazor web app in .net 8. Please take a look at what I shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77656889/14574199). It includes a workaround for how to add AAD in to a new blazor web app server-side-rendered app, and a workaround for how to upgrade a blazor server with AAD integrated from .net 7 to .net 8

Answer (score 2):

For Blazor Server App, there is no .NET8.0 version available.

Even I have checked in the latest VS 17.9.0 Preview Version.

[image]

`Microsoft Identity Platform` for .NET 8.0 is currently not supported for `Blazor WebApp Template`.

- But you can find and option to configure it from the `Connected Services`.

[image]

- This option will create an App Registration and the necessary configuration is done in the registered App.

[image]

- The below NuGet Packages are installed in the  app. Check your `.csproj` file.

```cs
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.16.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.16.0"
```

- You need to add the code and configuration manually.

Refer [Microsoft Identity Authentication - Blazor Web App](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Microsoft-Identity-Platform-Authentication-in-Blazor-Web-Application/) and [Authentication to Blazor Web Apps](https://auth0.com/blog/auth0-authentication-blazor-web-apps/) to get the configuration and try to configure same in `.NET8.0` with latest NuGet Packages.

Comment: I am getting build errors or depending on the choices I make even failures during the update. I will remain on NET6 for now.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I didn't look into fixing it, I moved to NET6 to be able to move on and it's still under LTS until November. We will check again at a later date when it's included in the template again.