Why does my Entra MSAL flow work for log in, but I get a 404 when logging out?
I am having a strange issue. I am using MSAL 2 with an Entra Customer tenant, and users can log in, but cannot log out.
Here's my sample configuration, which I had to change from the original documentation due to a bug where if you are not a global admin, you cannot login.
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://55...67.ciamlogin.com/55...67/v2.0",
    "Instance": "https://55...67.ciamlogin.com/55...67/v2.0",
    "Domain": "exampleTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "44...56",
    "ClientSecret": "{{omitted}}",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    // the following is required to handle Continuous Access Evaluation challenges
    "ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "Scopes": "User.ReadBasic.All user.read email"
  }

My DI Registration:
private static void RegisterAuthentication(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{

    var authenticatedPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    // <ms_docref_add_msal>
    IEnumerable<string>? initialScopes = configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddDownstreamApi("DownstreamApi", configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    // </ms_docref_add_msal>

    // <ms_docref_add_default_controller_for_sign-in-out>
    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authenticatedPolicy));
        //filters omitted for brevity
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    // </ms_docref_add_default_controller_for_sign-in-out>

    services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
    services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        //policies omitted for brevity
        .AddFallbackPolicy(PolicyConstants.MustBeAuthenticated, authenticatedPolicy);
}

And then, for clarity, here's the app configuration
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(MyClientApp._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();

Then, I have a redirect for unauthenticated users to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn.  This works great.  Users are sent to login and come back authenticated with claims.
Now I wanted to add a logout link
<a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut" class="ti-dropdown-item">
    <i class="ti ti-logout  text-lg"></i>
    Sign Out
</a>

However, when the redirection happens, MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut throws a 404.  I think it's odd that signin works, but signout does not.

I had a test before which integrating AAD in a blazor web app and that sample worked well in sign out. Could you pls check it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730702/14574199

I was missing app.AddRouting(); and app.MapControllers(); and once I added them, the sign out worked. Thank you!

Does this answer your question? Does Msal work with Blazor V8 release? And where should the Msal components be located?

@Josh  Pls allow me to post your solution below to end this question. Thank you very much for your sharing!

OP is facing 404 error when hitting the AAD sign out action.
Based on the confirmation from OP, lacking of app.AddRouting(); and app.MapControllers(); caused the issue.
